# Are there any champions for which leveling the ultimate when it's possible isn't advisable?

Tags: league-of-legends

Whenever I play any champion in LoL I know that I have to level up my "R" as soon as I can, because in general it's the most important skill etc.

What I was wondering is, are there any champions who do not gain much from reducing the cooldown (for those which have an utility as R, for example) and should rather use the point for something else?

I thought that for Rek'Sai this could be true, but I can't think of any other champion (besides Karma whose ultimate does not level up at all) who should even think of doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say most Champion benefit greatly from maxing His R as soon as posible.
But there are some that you can pass that point.

There are some champion than begin already with their ultimate at level 1:

Jayce,
Nidalee,
Elise,
Karma

In the case of Karma and Nidalee, the reduced CD /increased damage is in my opinion really needed.

Jayce and elise on the other way aren't really entitled to it.
Elise gains another spider for her passive ( it is an increase in sustained damage and healing thanks to W)

And jayce increases a bit his first autoattack bonus , slight increase in %defense reduction in canon form and increase in the on hit damage of the hammer form.

Udyr is a special case because he can level any ability and leaving one at only 3 points,
the specific level up is dependant on the build on is folowing and the needs oneself has.

For the more "normal" champions:
Olaf,Pantheon,Poppy and Rengar can live and be Effective with only 1 point in their ultimate.
The trade-off for each one compared to an always when possible point in R:

Olaf: Less attack damage.

Pantheon: Longer Cooldown, Less damage.

Poppy: Longer Cooldown , Duration is shorter.

Rengar: Longer Cooldown.

Sources: Own Experience and leagueoflegends.com champion profiles

Comment: Zilean. Having R lvl 1 is enough.

Comment: @dyesdyes It can be enough but you loose a lot of extra healing and a greatly reduced cooldown for an ult. It's not the same to revive with a 1/4 of health than nearly full even on a tank.

Comment: I'd add Sivir, situationally. Sometimes I delay her ultimate if I feel that, at that moment, I need the poke from her Q or clear from her W more, or even her E if I feel that the shield may help me win a duel that I would otherwise lose, and that her ult won't let me escape from.

Answer (score 0):

Pantheon is a good example.

I would max E first before getting a second point in R. Because his R is mostly used for providing utility and not damage.

I agree on your Rek'Sai theory. I would max another Skill before getting e second point in R

Comment: Rek'sai's ultimate increases her attack speed by 20% per point as well as reducing the cooldown by 40 seconds (150/110/70), I think on the first point alone it is worth taking each time it levels up.  However, it is definitely often used early/mid game as a quick way to get back to farming (especially in jungle) so if one point in a different ability will let you farm faster it may be worth skipping.